# Curl: Save HTTP Error in Bash to log and data to file

Tags: bash, curl

I'm making a `curl` request to a REST API and now I want to save the HTTP answer code, just if an error occurs, to a logfile and the API answer to another file if there is no error occuring.

I'm trying it with:

```
error=$(curl -v -o "test.json" -H "Authorization: Basic ABCDEF" "https://api.abc.com")
```

and

```
error=$(curl --fail -o "test.json" -H "Authorization: Basic ABCDEF" "https://api.abc.com")
```

If I make an `if [0 -eq $? ]` after the `curl` request with `--fail` I can detect that an error occurred but I am not able to save the HTTP error to a log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since according `man curl` the option `--fail`

> ... is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

you could use `--write-out` and `http_code`.

> The numerical response code that was found in the last retrieved HTTP(S) or FTP(s) transfer.

I.e.:

```
ERROR=$(curl --silent --fail --header "Authorization: Basic ABCDEF" "https://api.abc.com" --output "test.json" --write-out "%{http_code}")
```

Comment: This works quite perfect, thanks!

But, i didn't get this problem with --fail. With your suggestion i would not need the --fail, is that correct?

Comment: @reinmanu, right, probably not, since according `man curl` the option `--fail` will "_enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22._"

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

This should do the trick.

```
#send all output to file named out
curl -v -o "test.json" -H "Authorization: Basic ABCDEF" "https://api.abc.com" >out 2>&1
# find HTTP/2 code in the output
error=`grep "HTTP/2" out | tail -1 | rev | cut -c1-5 | rev`
# print the error code
echo $error
```

Example run:

```
mamuns-mac:jenkins xmrashid$ ./get_error.sh
503 
mamuns-mac:jenkins xmrashid$
```

Good Luck.

Comment: I'm working with the output file in some other programs and bashs afterwards and i'm not sure if i can rely on this that there is no other content (e.g. errornumbers which i didn't got out with get) left in the output file...

And, with this i get every http code, also the good ones is that right?

Comment: Looks like U880D's works better! That's great. Best of luck.